# replacing $ and # from file

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have file with comments like this:

```
\$max_servers = 2;    

\#\## BLOCKED ANYWHERE
```

I'm trying to

- Replace all instances of `\$` with `$`.
- Replace all instances of `\#\##` with `###`.

I wonder how I can go about doing that via sed or awk

What I have tried so far without much success using vi or vim

```
%s/^\//gc

%s/^#/\\/###/gc
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option to replace all [#$] in one pass is to use the following regular expression. The following is VI syntax:

```
:%s/\\\([$#]\)/\1/g
```

Replace the characters in the brackets `[]` with whatever you need if its more than just `#` and `$`.

The first `\\` is a backslash - escaped since its inside a regular expression
The expression between the `\(` and `\)` is saved and later used in the replacement as `\1`.

Answer (score 1):

You escape special characters with the backslash.  So for example, to replace everything with \$, you would do
    `%s/\\\$/$/g`

Comment: You don't need to escape the `$` in the replacement.

Comment: Okay, I fixed that now.

Answer (score 1):

Escaping backslash will work

```
 #echo "\#\##"| sed "s/\\\\#\\\\##/###/g"
 ###
 # echo "\\$"| sed "s/\\\\\\$/$/g"
 $
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to replace a backslash, you have to double it up, so it can *quote itself* much the way other special characters must be quoted. You can use `sed` instead of `vim` to help automate the process a bit:

```
$ sed -e 's/^\\\$/$/' -e 's/^\\#\\##/###/' $file > $new_file
```

Note that you have to put a backslash in front of dollar signs since they are used to mark an end of line in regular expressions. That's why I have `\\\$` in my first expression. One backslash to quote the backslash and another backslash to quote the dollar sign.

By the way, these same sed expressions will also work inside Vim depending upon your Vim settings.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's|^\\\([$#]\)\\\{0,1\}|\1|' YourFile
```

work for your sample bu will also remove the 2 `\` in `\$\ ...`,